# Using React with uncontrolled third-party components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I'd like to create a UI similar to JSFiddle using React:

- A panel for HTML, CSS and JS
- A preview panel
- A single "Run" button that updates the preview

I'd like to use Microsoft's [Monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) for the HTML, CSS and JS panels to get syntax highlight and autocomplete.

I've abstracted out a generic MonacoEditor component. My component hierarchy looks something like this:

```
<Root>
  <div>HTML <MonacoEditor /></div>
  <div>CSS <MonacoEditor /></div>
  <div>JS <MonacoEditor /></div>
  <button onClick={this.run}>Run</button>
  <PreviewPanel />
</Root>
```

If I were implementing this UI in Vanilla JS, the `run()` method would call [`getValue()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/9ff02988e64369aeffcfe30a60e52ffc6906aa56/website/playground/monaco.d.ts.txt#L1852-L1858) on each Monaco instance to extract the full text from each panel and generate the preview.

This becomes awkward with React, however, since the `run()` method can't call methods on instances of child components.

One workaround would be for the `MonacoEditor` to have an `onUpdate` prop which gets fired on every keystroke. The `Root` component could store the provisional contents of each panel for when the "Run" button was clicked. This is what I might do if each editor were a `<textarea>`. But it's a non-starter with Monaco. Serializing the text of the editor on every keystroke makes it unusably slow.

The only other approach I can think of is passing in a "getter setter" to the `MonacoEditor` component, e.g.:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MonacoEditor setGetter={getter => this.getHTML=getter} />
        <MonacoEditor setGetter={getter => this.getCSS=getter} />
        <MonacoEditor setGetter={getter => this.getJS=getter} />
        <button onClick={() => this.run()}>Run</button>
        <PreviewPanel />
      </div>
    );
  }

  run() {
    const html = this.getHTML();
    const css = this.getCSS();
    const js = this.getJS();
    // ...
  }
}
```

But this feels extremely awkward and counter to the idea of one-way databinding. Is there a better, more idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [react-monaco-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-monaco-editor).

This will satisfy all your requirements! Especially [getting value from the editor instance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-monaco-editor#how-to-get-value-of-editor).

If not this, declare a function inside the editor component and use `ref` to call that function from other components.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The general principle here is that you can use a `ref` to get a reference to an instance of the component. This can expose instance-specific methods, e.g. `getValue()`. This is a bit counter to the spirit of React's data flow model, but it's certainly convenient!